# Translate is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, localisation

my xml code:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" ifconfig="example/general/enabled" module="example" translate="label">
            <name>example</name>
            <path>example/list/</path>
            <label>My Example</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

I m using translate="label" but its not working i dont know why but in admin side its working

Comment: Is there a definition for `example` as helper alias in your `config.xml`? And does the default helper `Namespace_Module_Helper_Data` exist?

Comment: yes its exist..

Comment: same issue here did you find anything for this?

Comment: For `addcrumb` action method in xml to translate this [Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182646/translation-not-working-from-xml-file/182659#182659)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have this in the `config.xml` of your module under the `<config>` tag.

```
<frontend>
    <translate>
       <modules>
            <[Namespace]_[Module]>
                <files>
                    <default>[Namespace]_[Module].csv</default>
                </files>
            </[Namespace]_[Module]>
        </modules>
    </translate> 
</frontend>
```

and make sure your text exists in the `[Namespace]_[Module].csv` file like this

```
"My Example","Translation goes here"
```

If this is the last line in your csv file make sure your have a new line at the end of it.

Comment: Not working...:(

Comment: Strange. That usually works for me. Did you clear the cache?

Comment: yup,i did it...