# Why the translation isn't working from XML file?

Tags: magento-1.8, xml, localisation

I'm using below code in my XML and translate it using **translate.csv**.

But it isn't working can anyone please help me?

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
    <reference name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>Beregn pris</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo>
                <label>Beregn pris</label>
                <title>Beregn pris</title>
                <link>/beregn-pris</link>
            </crumbInfo>
        </action>
        <action method="addCrumb" translate="label" module="checkout">
            <crumbName>Cart</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo>
                <label>Indkøbskurv</label>
                <title>Indkøbskurv</title>
            </crumbInfo>
        </action>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Answer (score 1):

**How the xml translate works ?**

When you see `translate="label" module="checkout"`, this one tells to Magento that it should pass the value in the <label> tag through the checkout module's **data helper's translate** method before displaying it.

**Eg:** `echo Mage::helper('checkout')->__('your string');`

If the module attribute is not present, the `core` module is used.  You may specify multiple tags to be translated with a space delimited string.

As far as I know, this is supported in the System Configuration section, and the layout xml <action> nodes (for translating paramaters) only.

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label" module="checkout"> //i added the module here
        ...
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code.

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb" translate="crumbInfo.label crumbInfo.title">
            <crumbName>Beregn pris</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo>
                <label>Beregn pris</label>
                <title>Beregn pris</title>
                <link>/beregn-pris</link>
            </crumbInfo>
        </action>
        <action method="addCrumb" translate="crumbInfo.label crumbInfo.title">
            <crumbName>Cart</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo>
                <label>Indkøbskurv</label>
                <title>Indkøbskurv</title>
            </crumbInfo>
        </action>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```