# Translate title in a config.xml file

Tags: magento2.4.3

I have a label for my tooltip in module-login-as-customer-assistance in the config.xml file. It looks like this:

/vendor/magento/module-login-as-customer-assistance/etc

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <login_as_customer>
        <general>
            <shopping_assistance_checkbox_title>Allow remote shopping assistance</shopping_assistance_checkbox_title>
            <shopping_assistance_checkbox_tooltip>This allows merchants to "see what you see" and take actions on your behalf in order to provide better assistance.</shopping_assistance_checkbox_tooltip>
        </general>
    </login_as_customer>
</default>
```

i added follow lines in my csv

This allows merchants to "see what you see" and take actions on your behalf in order to provide better assistance.,translate any langage,module,Magento_LoginAsCustomerAssistance

Unfortunately, despite 'translate' parameter the output in the front end is still 'This allows merchants to "see what you see" and take actions on your behalf in order to provide better assistance.'. I've updated translation file, flushed the cache but it didn't help. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated :)?

Comment: I can imagine this has something to do with the double quotes. Maybe escape those with a backslash?

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/72506

Answer (score 1):

With this it is working as expected.

This allows merchants to ""see what you see"" and take actions on your behalf in order to provide better assistance.,translate any language,module,Magento_LoginAsCustomerAssistance

add to language .csv